# How to warmup a serverless lambda with child routes in nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I have created a lambda function in nodejs with child route 
Here my structure:

- lib

  - routes

    - notes

      - note.js
      - notes.controller.js
    - otherRoutes
    - index.js
  - app.js
  - db.js
- serverless.yml

Here index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const notes = require('./notes/notes.controller');
router.use('/notes', notes);
router.use('/otherRoutes', otherRoutes);
module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

/*CORS*/
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );
    next();
});
const helmet = require('helmet');
app.use(helmet());
require('./db');
const routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/', routes);

module.exports = app;
```

notes.controller.js

```
const express = require('express');
const notesController = express.Router();
const Note = require('./note');

notesController
    .post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
        const note = await Note.create(req.body);
        res.status(200).send(note)
    });

notesController
    .put('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
        const note = await Note.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
            { $set: req.body },
            { $upsert: true, new: true });
        res.status(200).send(note)
    });

notesController
    .get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
        const notes = await Note.find();
        res.status(200).send(notes)
    });

notesController
    .get('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
        const note = await Note.findById(req.params.id);
        res.status(200).send(note)
    });

notesController
    .delete('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
        const note = await Note.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id });
        res.status(200).send(note)
    });

module.exports = notesController;
```

I want to warmup  my lambda function and I followed this tutorial :
https://serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-warmup/ 
But the structure is different because it is multiple lambda function. In my structure, it is one lambda function with multiple child routes. 
Do you know how can I warmup my lambda function with child routes please ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since re:Invent this week, setting up complicated warming strategies for Lambda functions are not necessary since a new feature calle Provisioned Concurrency was launched and is supported by the Serverless Framework. Just add one line to your serverless.yml file under the function you want the provisioned concurrency set for with how many warm Lambda instances you want and you are all set:

```
    provisionedConcurrency: 3
```

Reference documentation for the Serverless Framework: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/

Blog post with a lot more detail: https://serverless.com/blog/aws-lambda-provisioned-concurrency/

Comment: Note that the Cloudwatch metrics are misbehaving and it might seem that your function is being throttled while in fact it's not. I've submitted a support request to AWS and got the following reply: "The issue seems to be, when Cloudwatch Metric calculates Throttles, it regards "ProvisionedConcurrency" as Concurrency limit (Like the traditional reserved Concurrency)". I've decided to wait until this is resolved before I enable the setting.

Comment: Update: your function will indeed be throttled. From AWS: "We are investigating an issue where a function with provisioned concurrency enabled may see unexpected throttles when actual concurrency exceeds the configured amount of provisioned concurrency. A fix is currently in the works, with an estimated rollout in early January. If throttles from spillover are affecting your workload, we currently recommend disabling provisioned concurrency until the fix is available. We will communicate once the fix has been deployed."